# HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found in DotNet

Tags: asp.net

When I am requesting the json file using ajax from dotnet application I got this error:

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Please share the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
 Implement below code in `web.config` file. Use the file extension that you want to fetch
 For Example: here is .json file

 <system.webServer>

 <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".json" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>

 </system.webServer>
```